# Blazor: Implementing 404 not found page

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-core-2.0, blazor

I'd like to implement a page internal to my application that appears when the blazor router is unable to find a matching route. Currently, all requests are routing to `index.html` so I'm unable to handle errors through iis as I may normally. If I enter an invalid route, I will be shown a blank page (which is actually `index.html`) and receive a console error:

`'Router' cannot find any component with a route for '/some/Nonexistent/Route'.`

It seems like I should be able to handle this since the blazor router is able to recognize that there is no route defined which matches the requested route however I've so far been unable to find any documentation on this.

How can I implement this? Is there a way to hook into the blazor router and direct all non found routes to a predefined error route?

I see https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/5489 has an issue listed for a 404 handler however I'm not sure if that is for something more robust and production ready than what I'm looking to do

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:
App.cshtml

```
<Router AppAssembly=typeof(Program).Assembly FallbackComponent="typeof(Error404)" >
```

Create a Component named Error404.cshtml

Note: This is only a guess I gathered from digging the Router class. See https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/343208331d9ebbb3a67880133f4139bee2cb1c71/src/Components/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components/Routing/Router.cs

Please, let me know if it works for you.

Comment: results in a runtime error right after launching the app: `Uncaught (in promise) Error: System.InvalidOperationException: Object of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Routing.Router' does not have a property matching the name 'FallbackComponent'.` which I find somewhat odd considering I can see a property named `FallBackComponent` marked as `[Parameter]` in the source file for the `Router` (I'm using Blazor v0.7.0 which should be current)

Comment: Looking at the history of that file, it looks like `FallbackComponent` was added 5 days ago (12/14/2018). Looks like it hasn't been included in a blazor release quite yet even on the supposed-to-be nightly builds feed at https://dotnet.myget.org/gallery/blazor-dev which pointing at the proper repo and they haven't updated the docs to supply us with the proper feed for CI feeds yet if there is one

Comment: I'm keeping an eye on this and will mark as accepted when a package that includes this source code is made available and I'm able to test it. Seems like this should work though

Comment: In `App.razor` there is a default `<NotFound>` element now.

Answer (score 8):

In `App.razor`, add the `<NotFound>` element under `<Router>` and set what content you'd like to be displayed when Blazor can't find the specified route.

For example:

```
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
    <NotFound>
        <h1>404 Not Found</h1>
    </NotFound>
</Router>
```

(Note: If it's a server side app, then it would be `@typeof(Startup).Assembly`)

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/th-th/aspnet/core/blazor/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.0#main)

Comment: But, will this approach return a 404 code? I just tested, and could not see 404 error code in the browser. A 404 error code can be very important for SEO.

Comment: @EmranHussain it appears hard to return a proper 404 code, but you should be able to acheive it using dependency injection. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62300957/565288

Comment: Has anyone ever made it to have a different NotFound page for Authorized and NotAuthorized views?  I can't seem to make it work...

Answer (score 2):

Program:

```
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/404");

app.Run();
```

Add a _404.razor page to your Pages folder:

```
@page "/404"
<h3>Show me 404</h3>
@code {
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For SEO enough add in App.razor:

```
<NotFound>
        <h1>404 Not Found</h1>
        <HeadContent>
               <meta name="robots" content="noindex" />
        </HeadContent>
</NotFound>
```

and implement Sitemap.xml

Answer (score 0):

You can use this link for .net 5.0 blazor server-side application.
You can handle 404 and status code correct

https://stackoverflow.com/a/69404900/2123797