# How to replace Blazor default "soft 404" with an actual 404 status code response

Tags: http-status-code-404, blazor

The default Blazor approach to 404 is to create a soft 404 in App.razor, but I would like to adhere to search engine best practices to actually return the 404 status code while displaying a 404 page on Azure.

I tried to remove the  element in App.razor to see if I could force a 404, however, that did not compile.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8):

I use this code. It works well.

I created Error404Layout. I use this layout for NotFound part.

```razor
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly" PreferExactMatches="@true">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(Error404Layout)">
            <h2>Oops! That page can't be found.</h2>
        </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>
</Router>
```

Error404Layout content below

```razor
    @inherits LayoutComponentBase

    @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
    @inject IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor

    @Body

    @code {
        protected override void OnInitialized()
        {
            httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 404;
       }
    }
```

You have to add this code in startup.cs / services method

```cs
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ....
        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
    }
```

I can see 404 status code

[image]

Comment: Thanks for replying. Are you sure this always returns a httpcontext. There could be some issues according to this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-5.0#blazor-and-shared-state

Comment: I'am searching better way.

Answer (score 3):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-3.1 does state:

> Additionally, again for security reasons, you must not use
> IHttpContextAccessor within Blazor apps. Blazor apps run outside of
> the context of the ASP.NET Core pipeline and the HttpContext isn't
> guaranteed to be available within the IHttpContextAccessor, nor it is
> guaranteed to be holding the context that started the Blazor app.

So you need to create a wrapper around IHttpContextAccessor to limit this when Blazor is being server side prerendered.

---

I was able to return 404 http status codes when using server side prerendering in the Blazor WebAssembly App (ASP.Net Core Hosted) Template

When I pointed the browser to http://localhost/fetchdata it returned a page. I wanted this to return a 404 status code as an example. This was possible using dependency injection and a stub class.

In **BlazorApp1.Client** I added a IResponse.cs file:

```
namespace BlazorApp1.Client {
    public interface IResponse {
        void SetNotFound();
    }
}
```

In BlazorApp1.Client I added a ResponseStub.cs file:

```
namespace BlazorApp1.Client {
    public class ResponseStub : IResponse {
        public void SetNotFound() {
            // Do nothing if we are browser side
        }
    }
}
```

In FetchData.razor in BlazorApp1.Client I added:

```
@inject BlazorApp1.Client.IResponse Response
```

and in the code section:

```
protected override void OnInitialized() {
    Response.SetNotFound();
}
```

In Program.cs in BlazorApp1.Client I added:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IResponse, ResponseStub>();
```

Then in **BlazorApp1.Server**, in Startup.cs I added under ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
services.AddScoped<IResponse, Response>();
```

and under Configure I replaced:

```
endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
```

with:

```
endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
```

Then create the Server implementation of IResponse in Response.cs:

```
using BlazorApp1.Client;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System.Net;

namespace BlazorApp1.Server {
    public class Response : IResponse {
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

        public Response(IHttpContextAccessor accessor) {
            _httpContextAccessor = accessor;
        }

        public void SetNotFound() {
            _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
        }
    }
}
```

And finally I create a _Host.cshtml file in BlazorApp1.Server/Pages:

```
@page "/fallback"
@namespace BlazorPrerendering.Server.Pages
@using BlazorApp1.Client
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}
<app>
    <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
</app>
<div id="blazor-error-ui">
    An unhandled error has occurred.
    <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
    <a class="dismiss"></a>
</div>
<script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

@ergin-Çelik Your solution works very well. I only had to add the following check because I got an error that the response had already been sent.

I have add this as answer because code formatting is better here.

```
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    if (_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext != null && 
        !_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.HasStarted)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
    }
}
```

Comment: does this work only on Serverside Blazor? Because Wasm will always return null for HttpContext