# Response actual 404 status code for missing endpoints (.NET 6, Blazor Server side)

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have an application written on .NET 6. This app has Web UI (Blazor Server side, render-mode="Server") and REST API.
Now to return custom 404 page I use  component like this.

```
<Router>
   <NotFound>
      ...
   </NotFound>
</Router>
```

But:

1. this method does not return 404 status (returned 200), that is strange.
2. for REST API request my app also return 200 status with html page, that is bad.

In both cases I need to return real 404 http status code when endpoint not found.

I read about IHttpContextAccessor in this answer [How to replace Blazor default "soft 404" with an actual 404 status code response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60239939/how-to-replace-blazor-default-soft-404-with-an-actual-404-status-code-response)
but according to Microsoft docs it is not recommended to use in blazor app. And to be honest, it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace Blazor default "soft 404" with an actual 404 status code response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60239939/how-to-replace-blazor-default-soft-404-with-an-actual-404-status-code-response)

Comment: I just saw you linked this, but I don't believe there is any other way to do this currently. There are upcoming changes in .NET 8 that may change how you can interact with the HTTPContext, but as of now you don't have many options