# Blazor fails on page reload

Tags: blazor

I used one of the VS2019 project templates to create a new Blazor app. The menu on the left in the app works, but as soon as I hit F5 or type in the URL e.g. https://localhost:44352/fetchdata the browser runs into 404 page not found. Any idea what might be the problem?

Comment: Did you see this answer? [Blazor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53859078/blazor-implementing-404-not-found-page)

Answer (score 1):

I was missing the MapFallbackToPage call in UseEndpoints.